# Name of textbox depends on where it is located in an ArrayList

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, textbox

I'm using VBA to code an application for an Excel file.  Put simply, I need the names of my textboxes to change depending on where a certain variable is in an ArrayList.

I have one textbox to start, when someone pushes a button it should add a textbox after the first one, and do this as many times as one presses the button.  So the first box should be named `tbx1`, the second should be `tbx2`, the third `tbx3`, and so on.

Now when they press a different button located next to any of the boxes, it deletes that box and button and all boxes after that one are named one lower to make up for it.

Any ideas how to do this?  I'm only assuming ArrayList is the best tactic, please correct me if there is a better way.

Comment: Why don't you first try using ArrayList and see what happens. Then post your code if you have specific questions regarding its implementation or errors.

Comment: Probably better to store them in a dictionary object since that is easier to add/remove items than with an array. Show your code if you have specific problems implementing either approach.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'll check out this Dictionary object you speak of and post my code for whichever gets me further.  Thanks guys.

Comment: See this link for everything could could possibly want to know about dictionary: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html :)

Comment: @DavidZemens So with Dictionary how could I remove one key and value and decrement all the other keys, and they still contain their respective values?

Comment: dictionary has a `.Delete` method which will remove a specified key/value pair. Then you do iteration over the remaining keys and modify the associated *value* as needed.

Comment: @DavidZemens Well that worked out!  Now I'm going to try to implement that into my application and I'll update my question once I've got something. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have to change the names? Whatever code logic you have that relies on names being a certain thing is what needs to be fixed, not the code that changes the names.

Comment: @DickKusleika This question was in conjunction with the one you answered yesterday, about dynamic command buttons.  I am basically creating a user interface for adding/deleting courses on a college degree checksheet.  So I need to dynamically add/remove new textboxes for course names. If you can help fix my code logic, that would be great.

Comment: What's the maximum number of textboxes they can have?

Comment: As many as memory can hold, theoretically.  My comment on your answer on the other question has my current issue.

Comment: But there's a practical limit. What's a degree? 150 hours? I think 75 textboxes would cover it where most classes are 3 credit hours.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.  And this is a two-year degree, so I could even make that smaller. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Just wondering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that you can hopefully modify to your needs.  I have a userform named UClassList with one commandbutton, cmdAdd, and one textbox, tbxClass_1.

```
Private mEventButtons As Collection

Public Property Get ClassMax() As Long
    ClassMax = 75
End Property

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Me.ClassMax
        'find the first invisible control and make it visible
        If Not Me.Controls("tbxClass_" & i).Visible Then
            Me.Controls("tbxClass_" & i).Visible = True
            Me.Controls("cmdClass_" & i).Visible = True
            Exit For 'stop after one
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim tbx As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim cmd As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim clsEventClass As CEventClass

    Set mEventButtons = New Collection

    'Add as many textboxes and commandbuttons as you need
    'or you can do this part at design time
    For i = 2 To Me.ClassMax
        Set tbx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "tbxClass_" & i, False)
        tbx.Top = Me.tbxClass_1.Top + ((i - 1) * 25) 'use the first textbox as the anchor
        tbx.Left = Me.tbxClass_1.Left
        tbx.Width = Me.tbxClass_1.Width
        tbx.Height = Me.tbxClass_1.Height

        'Create a delete commandbutton
        Set cmd = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmdClass_" & i, False)
        cmd.Top = tbx.Top
        cmd.Left = tbx.Left + tbx.Width + 10
        cmd.Width = 20
        cmd.Height = tbx.Height
        cmd.Caption = "X"

        'add delete commandbutton to the event class so they all share
        'the same click event code
        Set clsEventClass = New CEventClass
        Set clsEventClass.cmdEvent = cmd
        mEventButtons.Add clsEventClass
    Next i

End Sub
```

I have a custom class named CEventClass.

```
Public WithEvents cmdEvent As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub cmdEvent_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lThisIndex As Long
    Dim tbxThis As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim tbxPrev As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim uf As UClassList

    Set uf = cmdEvent.Parent
    'get the number that was clicked
    lThisIndex = Val(Split(cmdEvent.Name, "_")(1))

    'loop from the next textbox to the end
    For i = lThisIndex + 1 To uf.ClassMax
        Set tbxThis = uf.Controls("tbxClass_" & i)
        Set tbxPrev = uf.Controls("tbxClass_" & i - 1)

        'if it's not visible, clear and hide
        'the previous textbox
        If Not tbxThis.Visible Then
            tbxPrev.Text = vbNullString
            tbxPrev.Visible = False
            uf.Controls("cmdClass_" & i - 1).Visible = False
        Else
            'if it's visible, copy it's text to the one above
            tbxPrev.Text = tbxThis.Text
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Instead of adding and deleting and keeping track of a bunch of textboxes, I create all 75 (or fewer) at launch (or design time). Then I just make then visible or hide them as needed.

You can see the workbook I did this on here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/excel/ControlEventClass.xlsm

Comment: Can I use this in several places on a userform, if I want different sections?

Comment: After looking around, if I wanted to use this in several places on a userform, should I use a TabStrip or a MultiPage?

Comment: You should create another question on the site.